# how to create dropdown list to fetch data from mysql for category>sybcategory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display two dropdown lists, one depending on the other. Being a beginner, I was unable to do this. I searched a lot but found none usefull. please help me out.

**My Controller is:**

```
    class CatvaluesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @catvalue = Catvalue.new
        @categories = Category.all
        @catvalues = Catvalue.all
        @catvalues_category = Catvalue.find(:all, :conditions => ['categories_id = ?',params[:id]])
    end

    def create
        @catvalue = Catvalue.new(params[:catvalue])
        if @catvalue.save
            redirect_to catvalues_path
        end
    end

    def show
        super
    end

  def destroy
    @catvalue_del = Catvalue.find(params[:id])
    @catvalue_del.destroy
    redirect_to catvalues_path
  end

end
```

**My Index file looks like**

```
<%=collection_select(:category, :id, @categories, :id,:c_name, {}, class: 'drop-down')%>
<%=collection_select(:catvalue, :id, @catvalues, :id, :v_name, {}, class: 'drop-down')%>
```

**and my DATABASE IS:**

```
mysql> desc categories;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| c_name     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> desc catvalues;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| v_name        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| categories_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And I want to select catvalues depending upon the category being selected like first Categories Dropdown followed by catvalues dropdown need to be displayed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format your post to fix all of the broken indentation.

Comment: am adding 4 spaces, but the code is not getting formatted..

Comment: Make sure you have an empty line before the indented block

Comment: I edited my answer.Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with [grouped_collection_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_collection_select).

Here is a [Railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised) which explains how to do this.Though you need a Pro subscription to view this.

And here is non-pro [Railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus?view=comments) of this which I just found out.Watch it,may help you.
Hope it helps!

Comment: am unable to use grouped_collection_select, can you please give syntax for my code above @pavan